# how do I write a formula with an IF and Vlookup that if the Vlookup returns a value of zero or less it returns a zero?

Tags: microsoft-excel

IF(E2>0,E2-VLOOKUP(C2,'Hourly Wages and Quota'!$A$2:$E$7,4,FALSE)*F2))

So if this forumula returns a negative number I want it to return a zero

How do I do this?

Comment: `=IF(E2>0,E2-VLOOKUP(C2,'Hourly Wages and Quota'!$A$2:$E$7,4,FALSE)*F2))=0,0,IF(E2>0,E2-VLOOKUP(C2,'Hourly Wages and Quota'!$A$2:$E$7,4,FALSE)*F2))`?

Comment: Your formula is invalid; it doesn't have the same number of left parentheses `(` and right parentheses `)`. And do you mean that you want a formula that evaluates to zero if the `VLOOKUP` returns a value of zero or less, or do you mean that you want a formula that evaluates to zero if the corrected version of the formula in your question returns a value of zero or less?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use nested IF:

`IF(E2>0,IF (E2-VLOOKUP(C2,'Hourly Wages and Quota'!$A$2:$E$7,4,FALSE)*F2<0,0,E2-VLOOKUP(C2,'Hourly Wages and Quota'!$A$2:$E$7,4,FALSE)*F2))`

Answer (score 0):

use

```
=MAX(0,YOURFORMULA)
```

more succinct and faster than nested IF